# What is the difference (if any) between (null != $object) and ($object != null) when using PHP?

Tags: php, object-oriented, code-quality, conditions

I am used to Java and therefore always think conditions are interpreted from left to right, i.e. there is a vital difference in `null != $obj` and `$obj != null`

Now this seems not to be the case with PHP.

Can I do something wrong in PHP when I always start with `null` on the left-hand side? Can I keep my behaviour from Java or do I need to train myself to do something else when dealing with PHP conditions?

Comment: There's no difference, but you should avoid [yoda conditions](http://wiert.me/2010/05/25/yoda-conditions-from-stackoverflow-new-programming-jargon-you-coined/), it's weird you think they are standard in Java or that there's any point in them, interpretation wise.

Comment: But woulndt that be an argument for always starting with null? Cause null = $a makes PHP choke where as $a = null would pass undetected.

Comment: `null = $a` is assignment and `null != $a` is comparison, did you mean `null == $a`? `null = $a` won't work, and yes in assignments order of interpretation is significant - and it wouldn't work in Java either. Are we talking conditionals or assignment?

Comment: lol ... aehm... ok. Sorry I wasn't making myself clear enough.....  Lets assume you make a mistake writing a condition and create a yoda expression. (like you said) And you produce a code line like: ($a = null). It will go through unnoticed cause you produced a legal condition. Now if I tell my team to ALWAYS start a condition with null (if a null check is used) on the LEFT HAND SIDE it could help to avoid this kind of mistake. Actually... I have just answered my own question thanks to your feedback. :-)

Comment: I see, that's perhaps one good reason in favour of yoda conditions. Feel free to post it as an answer if you want, it's perfectly ok to answer your own questions.

Comment: In what way does it differ from Java?

Comment: @YannisRizos: Well my reputation is to low to answer my own question... *chuckle*

Comment: Hm, apparently you'll have to wait a couple of hours, I guess it's an anti spam thing. Please do move your answer from the question into an answer when you can, we prefer answers to be clearly identifiable as such.

Comment: @anann - please feel free to use the answer I added capturing your comments and Yannis'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- There is no (technical) difference – nor is there in Java to my knowledge.
- In PHP, do not use either of these.

I recommend you always use the strict comparison operators `===` and `!==` if possible. You will know when you actually *need* loose comparison operators.

### Misunderstandings

I believe you may be confused about a couple of things:

- short-circuiting operators
- order of evaluation
- operator precedence

> I just found that the PHP manual says:
>   "PHP checks each condition in order from left to right"

No,

- the PHP *manual* does **not** say that, it's a comment.
- PHP does **not** do that.

PHP evaluates the *conditions* from left to right, but it stops once the result is known:

```php
expr1 && expr2
```

If `expr1` evaluates to `false`, `expr2` will *not* be evaluated. This is called short-circuiting and it [does not seem to be very well-*documented*](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) – I couldn't find any other official note on the matter except for the comment in Example #1. It is a well-*known* feature, though.

### Fallacies

> I am used to Java and therefore always think conditions are interpreted from left to right, i.e. there is a vital difference in null != $obj and $obj != null

---

> PHP checks each condition in order from left to right
>   Ergo: The same "best practice" can be applied

Ergo: *nothing* – non sequitur. The conclusion does not follow from the premise. Using `constant == $variable` or `$variable == constant` is not connected to either of *short-circuiting*, *order of evaluation* or *operator precedence*.

### Undefined behavior

Both operands of `!=` are *always* evaluated. In the case of PHP, the evaluation order (which is irrelevant here) is actually [unspecified](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=61188) (as in absent from the documentation).

Comment: Thx for your clarification on the topic. Although I don't like you tone regarding my Java Knowledge. (See Section 15.7 of the Java Language Specification) Lets sum it up. The order of evaluation is unspecified in PHP and therefor you can not rely on it! 2nd never use != or == user === or !==.

Comment: @anann I'm not sure where you think I'm "rating" your Java knowledge. The only thing I did say is: `"nor is there in Java to my knowledge."` I have read section 15.7, but it is not important *here*. As long as you have no side-effects in your comparison (as in your example), the order of evaluation doesn't matter. Which part do you find to be offending?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your particular case another approach would be to used the built-in php function is_null. So you would end up with is_null($mixedValue) which would do all the work for you and properly do type comparison and everything else.

Answer (score -1):

@phant0m: OK point taken... NEVER USE != or == always use !=== and === when you code with PHP. Therefore this question was wrong in the beginning, and there is no best practice with NULL on either side of the condition when it comes to PHP.

Comment: It's a tradeoff. You sacrifice readability for safety (`$a == NULL` encodes intent, `NULL == $a` adds a safeguard), and this safety isn't even that strong because you're still relying on manual work (habits) rather than uncheatable automated checks. I don't think the tradeoff is worth it, but that's a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: Oh, and I always assumed 'yoda condition' referred to reversing the subject and the object in your conditions, so that they read "if twenty-three apples you have" (`23 == num_apples`) rather than "if you have twenty-three apples" (`num_apples == 23`).

Comment: You seemed to be confused on what a "Yoda-statement" is. It is "Yoda" when you put the NULL (or the constant part of the expression) on the left: http://gordienoye.ca/2012/02/07/when-yoda-writes-if-statements/

Comment: Also php does warn you if you do this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/718415/14065 you should be checking your error logs for warnigns and errors and fixing them all. Yoda style was all the rage in the 90's. The claim was that it solved this group of problems. In reality it makes the code harder to read and the compilers (interpreters) for most languages already warn you about the problem. So there is no real benefit to using them (assuming you make sure your code runs warning free (which you should do anyway)). A better solution is not to do assignment in conditionals (thus run warning free).

Comment: @tdammers Readability is opinion, so for those of us that have no problem with them, "yoda-conditionals" are what we tend to default to.  My eyes are drawn to the conditional first, so order doesn't help or harm.  Even for `>` and `<`, I'll read it more like "If that one is bigger", then read the one that should be bigger for the conditional to pass, then the other side.

Comment: @Izkata: There is at least a grain of objective truth in readability in this context: code *is* easier to read if it follows the sentence structure of the natural language it suggests (which is usually English). Of course you can train yourself to read code that doesn't do this with the same amount of ease, but that's not the point.

Comment: @tdammers My point is that I didn't train myself at all, though.  It is natural for some of us - and my first/primary language _is_ English.

Comment: I don't think it would have been necessary to basically "remove" your answer, you could also have posted that as a comment to my answer. I wasn't trying to say that you should `"NEVER"` use `!=` or `==`, but that you should know when you need it. Note that I made no argument about whether `constant == $obj` is preferable over `$obj == constant`.